# Better/Efficient Ways to Parsing Nested JSON Column from Spark Table

Tags: json, dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark and Scala. I am trying to parse a Nested JSON format column from a Spark Table. Here is a sneak peek of the table (I only show the first row from the Spark Table, they all look identical for the rest of it)

```
doc.show(1)

  doc_content                      object_id      object_version       
{"id":"lni001","pub_date"....       20220301         7098727
```

The structure of the **"doc_content"** column of each row looks like this (Some rows may have more information store inside the **'content'** field):

```
{
   "id":"lni001",
   "pub_date":"20220301",
   "doc_id":"7098727",
   "unique_id":"64WP-UI-POLI",
   "content":[
      {
         "c_id":"002",
         "p_id":"P02",
         "type":"org",
         "source":"internet"  
      },
      {
         "c_id":"003",
         "p_id":"P03",
         "type":"org",
         "source":"internet" 
      },
      {
         "c_id":"005",
         "p_id":"K01",
         "type":"people",
         "source":"news" 
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried to use `explode` on the "doc_content" column

```
doc.select(explode($"doc_content") as "doc_content")
    .withColumn("id", col("doc_info.id"))
    .withColumn("pub_date", col("doc_info.pub_date"))
    .withColumn("doc_id", col("doc_info.doc_id"))
    .withColumn("unique_id", col("doc_info.unique_id"))
    .withColumn("content", col("doc_info.content"))
    .withColumn("content", explode($"content"))
    .withColumn("c_id", col("content.c_id"))
    .withColumn("p_id", col("content.p_id"))
    .withColumn("type", col("content.type"))
    .withColumn("source", col("content.source"))
    .drop(col("doc_content"))
    .drop(col("content"))
    .show()
```

but I got this error `` org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'explode(`doc_content`)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not string; ``. I am struggling on converting the column into Array or Map type (Probably new to Scala LOL).

After parsing the "doc_content" column, I want the table look like this.

```
  id          pub_date      doc_id       unique_id     c_id    p_id   type     source    oject_id     object_version
lni001        20220301      7098727     64WP-UI-POLI    002     P02    org    internet   20220301         7098727  
lni001        20220301      7098727     64WP-UI-POLI    003     P03    org    internet   20220301         7098727  
lni001        20220301      7098727     64WP-UI-POLI    005     K01   people    news     20220301         7098727
```

I am wondering how can I do this and it will be great I can get some ideas or approaches on how to do this. Or maybe a better way than my approach since I have million of rows inside the Spark Table, if I can make it run faster.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `from_json` to parses the JSON string into a MapType, then use `explode` on a array column to create new rows, what means you should explode on `doc_content.content` than `doc_content`.

Specify the schema to use parsing the json string:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = new StructType()
  .add("id", StringType)
  .add("pub_date", StringType)
  .add("doc_id", StringType)
  .add("unique_id", StringType)
  .add("content", ArrayType(MapType(StringType, StringType)))
```

then parse the json string and explode it

```
df.select(
  $"object_id",
  $"object_version",
  from_json($"doc_content", schema).alias("doc_content")
).select(
  $"object_id",
  $"object_version",
  col("doc_content.id").alias("id"),
  col("doc_content.pub_date").alias("pub_date"),
  col("doc_content.doc_id").alias("doc_id"),
  col("doc_content.unique_id").alias("unique_id"),
  explode(col("doc_content.content")).alias("content")
).select(
  $"id",
  $"pub_date",
  $"doc_id",
  $"unique_id",
  col("content.c_id").alias("c_id"),
  col("content.p_id").alias("p_id"),
  col("content.type").alias("type"),
  col("content.source").alias("source"),
  $"object_id",
  $"object_version"
)
```